# GraphQL: Stop Neo4jGraphQL translate my models during generation

Tags: neo4j, graphql, graphql-schema

I'm an experienced developer, but rather new to GraphQL.
I use [this Neo4j-Tutorial as a basis](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/getting-started/) for orientation and am developing in typescript (backend and frontend).

Can anyone tell me how to **somehow rename the generated Endpoints** from `@neo4j/graphql`? The [corresponding docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/2.0/) don't help with that.

I use the following GraphQL-Schema for demonstration (it's german: "Person" means "person" and "Tier" means "animal"):

```
type Person {
  name: String
}

type Tier {
  name: String
}
```

I process the schema using the `gql`-Function (from `apollo-server`) first, the result of that does look OK.

Afterwards, when I call `const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({ typeDefs, driver: drv })` (with drv being my Neo4j-Driver) the resulting `neoSchema.schema` shows up some unexpected naming in the generated endpoints, e.g.:

```
    CreatePeopleMutationResponse: CreatePeopleMutationResponse,
    UpdatePeopleMutationResponse: UpdatePeopleMutationResponse,
```

Somehow the german "Person" (plural being *"Personen"*) got implicitly translated to *"people"*. I can also think of some "false friends" where this effect is even worse.

Well, the API should be in my own language (following DDD), so that's a smell I want to rename also having the api-users and generated clients in mind. How is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: best to report it directly as an issue of the library: https://github.com/neo4j/graphql

Comment: Well, is it an issue or a missing feature? I did hope someone knew an option I don't get.

Comment: I think it somehow adds plural, but there isn't a way to rename it AFAIK, so it would be good to bring it to library authors to consider it, maybe they can also help you more

Comment: Thank you, opened [an issue for that](https://github.com/neo4j/graphql/issues/424).